Flutter: Drag and Drop, Resize and Reordering of Flutter Widgets
I need help on the implementation of widgets that can be dragged, resized and reordered in a customizable grid of tiles.
Basically i am asking if there is something in flutter that provides the base functionality of the Android Home Launcher where you can drag and drop widgets around.
So in summary:

a widget can be dragged around

a widget should snap to the tiles on the background.

a widget should be resizable, as in it can be a 1x1, 2x2, 3x4, 2x5 etc widget.

a widget can be dragged to a slot where another widget already sits, in that case they should change their slots. If thats not possible, a complete reordering of the widget should be done to make space for where the user wants to drop the widget.


I was looking at the draggable class in flutter, but then i got stuck on how to make it snap to the background tiles or how to resize and implement a reordering of all widgets.

it is super custom so you should implement it manually. there is no any library etc for that.

Draggable would do more harm than help - instead use simple Stack with Positioned GestureDetectors

"instead use simple Stack with Positioned GestureDetectors" - something like https://gist.github.com/pskink/468b0ed8859a85f94f0040c552e3a488, - notice how snapping is implemented with `rect getter
